# Get values of HashMap in ComboItem

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I am trying to build a combobox taken values from a HashMap. The problem is that the combo is empty. Why?

Here my code, `dateOptions` is a `HashMap<String,String>`

```
<template name="model" var="dettProduct">
                        <row>
                            <detail >
                                <div
                                    children="@load(dettProduct.dateProd)">
                                    <template name="children"
                                        var="date">
                                        <combobox
                                            model="@load(date.dateOptions.entrySet())" >
                                            <template name="model"
                                                var="dateValue">
                                                <comboitem
                                                    label="@load(dateValue.value)"
                                                    value="@load(dateValue.key)" />
                                            </template>
                                        </combobox>
                                    </template>
                                </div>
                            </detail>
                        </row>
                    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I look at this particulare code, it looks correct.
The only thing what's strange, but not impossible is the `date` what you take as viewmodel or reference.

I [created a fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/8gpti3/4-Map-databinding), where it works, so please check your version in this fiddle.

Comment: if `date` is a list => should `@load(date.get(0).dateOptions.entrySet()` wouldn't work? If possible, edit your question and attach more code or try to reproduce your problem in a fiddle.

Comment: date is a list of an object that i use in my vm, my fear is that is too nestled. Your code is the same as one of my attempts, but i doesn't work. I have tried to do so, just to check if the map contain the values:
`<div children="@load(date.dateOptions)">
            <template name="children"
             var="dateValue">
             <label value="@load(dateValue)" />
            </template>
           </div>`
And it stamp inside the value:
{2=DTPFT01, 1=DTPFT00}
{}

Comment: If I have the right setup I can help you, but I need to see how it's nested.

Comment: I think your problem is the grid with detail. Your detail is empty and not the combobox. try adding `<label value="test"/>` before your detail and check again.  In mine setup it works (as long I have 1 entry before the detail)